# How to align a View's top to another View's vertical center?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I need to align `View2` top-left corner to `View1`'s center, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing it in programmatically or only in XML?

Comment: @KenWolf No, I haven't. I know how to do it in code, very simple, just take View1's measures and coordinates and and relocate View2 accordingly. I am trying to do it in XML. Unless there is no other choice.

Comment: Check these ,they might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758932/layouts-on-top-of-each-other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629940/how-to-layer-views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888337/how-do-i-put-buttons-on-top-of-each-other-in-same-xml-layout

Comment: @ilomambo can't see how you'd do it in XML without absolutely specifying dimensions, etc...but let's see :)

Comment: @RachitaNanda thanks, but none of those were helpful to my problem

Comment: @KenWolf I think maybe creating a `quarterView1` and putting it invisible on top of `View1` and then aligning `View2` to its bottom & right.

Comment: @ilomambo sure but you'd still need to specify widths right? How big is quarterView1? How can you make it 1/4 of View1? I would just do it in code.

Comment: @KenWolf You're probably right. It seems nobody at android's SDK team thought that `layout_toCenterOf` is a needed attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it!

Make an xml like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FFFF99" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#440000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/view1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#99004400"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activty

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
         LinearLayout v1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view1);
            LinearLayout v2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view2);
            LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
            int heightV1=v1.getHeight();
            int widthV1=v1.getWidth();
            container.setPadding(widthV1/2, heightV1/2, 0, 0);
    }
```

Gives output like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gpsViewLayoutParams = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
this.relativeLayout.addView(gpsView,gpsViewLayoutParams);
```

Comment: ????? Did you paste the right code? I only see one view there, aligned to its parent top-right corner.

Answer (score -3):

Is this of any help to you?

```
<RelativeLayout>
<View1 />
<View2
 Layout_marginTop= (view1Height/2)+view1margin
 Layout_marginLeft=(view1Width/2)+view1margin /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```